# Can a HomeKit device directly see states/changes of other devices?

Tags: architecture, homekit

For some time already I am developing my own “virtual” HomeKit accessories - there is a software bridge with couple of accessories which is implemented in Scala (using a Java HomeKit accessory library). With this, I am for example able to turn on/off a TV or a sound-bar (using some different APIs). As a specific example, I have implemented a HomeKit power switch device which allows me (via HomeKit) to turn the TV on/off.

My question is: can my accessory directly read the state (and listen on changes) of another accessory from my home?

Stupid example: I have a Philips Hue lamp in the living room. If I turn off the lamp, I want to let the TV know that the light is now turn off and to decide whether it should turn off as well or not.

If I want just to turn off the TV *anytime* the lamp is off, that would be easy: I would set up an Automation in Home app which would set the “TV switch” to off anytime the lamp is off. But that’s too simple. Imagine you want to decide on multiple parameters and multiple states of different devices.

Currently, I am simulating this by having some artificial switches on my bridge, and setting them on and off using Automations on the real devices. An example again: I have a programmatic switch called “Living room light state” and there are two Automations - anytime the Hue lamp turns on, turn the state on; anytime the Hue lamp turns off, turn the state off. With this, I will get the knowledge of the current state of the Hue lamp to my application (the virtual bridge).

Can I read the state and listen for changes of the Hue lamp directly? Or is the HomeKit protocol meant really only for communication between an accessory/bridge and an iOS app which is aware of the home setup?

I sometimes read that “HomeKit is a protocol for communication between accessories” but honestly I haven’t ever seen any example and I haven’t found a way how could I let my accessories/bridge to find some other accessory in my home and listen to its changes.

**EDIT:** *Better example why I need this:* I have a thermometer and a light-level sensor, which don't have some binary or enumerated states – their current "states" are basically numbers (degrees of Celsius and luxes, respectively). I haven't find a way how to read these numbers at all. For this use-case, I don't even have any workaround compared to the situation described above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still relevant to you, but I think I can give you some answers and a hint towards the right direction.

No, AFAIK two accessories cannot communicate over HomeKit.

However, I don't think your requirements exceed the possibilities of HomeKit. The reason why you think so is that the Home app does not nearly support all of HomeKit's features.

The type of automation you want is a [`HMEventTrigger`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/homekit/hmeventtrigger).
This automation is triggered by a `HMEvent`. You are especially interested in [`HMCharacteristicEvent`s](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/homekit/hmeventtrigger/characteristic_events).
N triggers of M characteristics belonging to L different services/accessories are supported.

Once the automation has been triggered, the `predicate` is evaluated. This `predicate` is a [`NSPredicate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate), so you can really do a lot with this...have a look at the docs. Afterwards, the automation is executed if the `predicate` did evaluate to `true`.

As I mentioned, the problem is that the Home app does not support all (most) of HomeKit's features. You can try how far you can get with third-party apps. The [Eve App](https://apps.apple.com/de/app/elgato-eve/id917695792) is pretty good (I think it supports Boolean-, Enum- and Number-characteristics for usage in automations), or you can try some of the paid HomeKit apps that are not manufacturer-specific (haven't tried those myself). The last option is to write an app yourself that fits your needs.